# Python extract quantifiable text (numbers)

Tags: python, regex, nlp

Hello I want to use python and extract text that is either a numeric value or a number spelled out plus the first word before and after the found value.

Example text:

> I have 2 brothers and they bought one car each. My oldest
>   brother invested 1,000 dollars.

Expected Output:

`'have 2 brothers', 'bought one car', 'invested 1,000 dollars'`

I have tried this >

```
>>> import re
>>> str = "I have 2 brothers and they bought one car each. My oldest brother invested 1,000 dollars."
>>> print re.findall("\d+", s)
['2']
```

however this only worked for finding a value not the spelled out term `one`. I also do not know what to use to get the word before and after the found word.

Comment: For numeric value, regex `\w+\b\s\b\d+(?:,\d+)*\b\s\w+` will work [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WDWSis/1)

Comment: You need to write down a series of rules for what "numeric value" means—it's obviously not just a string of digits, because `1,000` has a non-digit character in it, but does that mean you want to accept, say, `1,2,3,4` as a numeric value? And, likewise, you need to write the rule for what "number spelled out" means. For example, are `forty-two` and `forty two` both numbers spelled out? `Twenty fifty-one`? Once you do that, you can translate it to a regular expression—but it will probably be a very complex and ugly one.

Comment: @Matt.G Using `\w` and `\d+(?:,\d+)*` seems [way too lenient here](https://regex101.com/r/oKjrk3/2).

Comment: @abarnert, thanks for finding the mistake. Updated regex `[A-Za-z]+\b\s\b\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\b\s[A-Za-z]+` will work [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oKjrk3/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quick and dirty regex:

```
pat = re.compile(r'(\w+\s+)([\d,]+|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)(\s+\w+)')
```

does produce the output you want. Of course it only finds single digits numbers spelled in English. For arbitrary numbers, you would need to use a proper parser. But it might suffice for what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you this works for the exact use case I need. I modified it a little bit [here](https://regex101.com/r/L1oZGy/4). Any idea how to add to find say '98%' , Digit followed by a % symbol?

Comment: You can just add `\d+%|` at the beginning of the second parenthesis of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that text form of numbers only goes from one to ten.

```
import re

text = 'I have 2 brothers and they bought one car each. My oldest brother invested 1,000 dollars.'
text_numbers = []
numbers = re.findall(r'[0-9,\-]+|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten', text)
for number in numbers:
    parts = text.split(number)
    first_part = parts[0].strip().split(' ')[-1]
    second_part = parts[1].strip().split(' ')[0]
    print('{} {} {}'.format(first_part, number, second_part))
```

Comment: Why use `str.split` when you've already defined the three parts separately in the regex, and you can just use three `(groups)`?

Comment: @abarnert you are right. frapadingue's solution does exactly that.